# E11000 duplicate key error with explicit _id assignment claiming it's null but it's actually not

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

It's the old E11000 error but with a twist (and yes I searched and found many of the same question but without the exact details that apply here - mainly the explicit `_id` assignment).

I'm manually assigning the `_id` field with `bson.NewObjectId()` because I need to return the ID back to the client - this was based on discussions from SO and GitHub, for example: https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/issues/453

https://github.com/Southclaws/ScavengeSurviveCore/blob/master/storage/player.go#L28-L32

The ID field is set up in the struct as:

```
ID bson.ObjectId `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
```

https://github.com/Southclaws/ScavengeSurviveCore/blob/master/types/player.go#L9-L23

So far I don't think I've missed anything. Unit tests create 3 instances of this object one after the other:

https://github.com/Southclaws/ScavengeSurviveCore/blob/master/server/handler_admin_test.go#L21-L56

First one gets created fine, it has an `_id` assigned to it (checked via mongo-express) and I even printed out the ID right before `.Insert` was called, same ID, everything is fine:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/68EJX.png]

```
CREATING {ObjectIdHex("5b092f4aff3055468e3ce00a") playerID1 (...)
```

Problem arises when the next of the three test records gets inserted - exact same code, and the log is printed:

```
CREATING {ObjectIdHex("5b092f4aff3055468e3ce00b") playerID2 (...)
```

but it returns an E11000:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: <db>.<collection> index: <collection>_id_1 dup key: { : null }
```

From what I can gather, it thinks `_id` is null but given all the evidence I can see, it's not null at all because `bson.NewObjectId()` is assigned to the `_id` field right before `.Insert` is called - *and* the object is printed out right before insertion and the ID is there.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `required,len=24"` It's not a "string". You're invalidating it and it's being removed. Just leave the field alone as all drivers must do a mandatory assignment of `_id` with an `ObjectId` by convention. In the event if it gets to the server with no `_id` field in the document at all ( as opposed to `null` ) then the "server" will assign the `ObjectId`. Always been the way it works, but your intervention is explicitly breaking this.

Comment: I've done manual assignment of the `_id` many times before, I was told it was the accepted way to do it if you need the ID returned to the client. I didn't think of the `validate` stuff though, I'll try removing that completely, it's from another library that isn't being used in this particular scenario but maybe mgo uses the same field name. - Edit: Nope, same issue still.

Comment: Show the type declaration, the way you create values of it and how you insert it. Aim for an [mcve]. As it is, this question is off-topic.

Comment: Sure thing @icza I've updated the main post with links to the source code and more explanation of what's going on.

Comment: Show us the code that returns the error, not the one that works.

Comment: I have, refresh and see the first post again.

Comment: Are you sure you run the same code? You claim the output log is `CREATING {ObjectIdHex("5b092f4aff3055468e3ce00b") playerID2 (...)`, but the code should log a different text: `fmt.Println("Creating types.Player with ID", player.ID)`...